# Why doesn't 'updated' get fired for a component when it has an array prop that is changed?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I created a child component with one prop of type Array. I expect the `updated` lifecycle event to fire whenever that array is modified from the parent using `push()`. This does not happen. I can see the changes take effect in the parent state, but those changes do not seem to get detected by the child component. What am I missing?

### Example Code

[See a 'working' demo on codepen.io](http://codepen.io/jessegavin/pen/XNyQJN)

**My view**

```
<div id="app">
  <child :items="items"></child>
  <button type="button" v-on:click="addItem()">Add Item</button>
</div>
```

**My script**

```
// Child component
Vue.component('child', {
  template: '<div>{{itemCount}}</div>',
  props: {
   items: Array
  },
  data: function() { 
    return { itemCount: 0 }
  },
  updated: function() {
    this.itemCount = this.items.length;
  }
})

// Main app
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    items: []
  },
  methods: {
    addItem: function() {
      this.items.push(Math.random());
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you notice the documentation of the [updated](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#updated), it says:

> Called after a data change causes the virtual DOM to be re-rendered and patched.

But in your case, you are not using `items`, anywhere in the DOM of the child component, so data change have no impacy on the virtual DOM and updated is not being called.

If you just add `items` in the div of child component, it will start working:

// Child component

```
Vue.component('child', {
  template: '<div>{{items}}::::{{itemCount}}</div>',
  props: {
   items: Array
  },
  ...
  ...
})
```

See working codepen [here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xRMJvV).

Comment: Thank you! I _did_ miss that in the docs. I know how to solve my issue now.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a computed property instead the `updated` callback.

`computed:{
    itemCount(){
        return this.items.length
    }
}`